# Lifecycle for IndexSearcher in Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I would like to have more understanding of the lifecycle for `IndexSearcher` in Solr, I understand that `IndexSearcher` for Lucene would recommend that “For performance reasons, if your index is unchanging, you should share a single `IndexSearcher` instance across multiple searches instead of creating a new one per-search.” ([Lucene 4.6.1](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html)).

But when things come to Solr world which in a Java Webapp with servlet dispatcher. Do we also keep reusing the same `IndexSearcher` instance as long as there is no index changing?

I see “Hossman” had this talk for the [lifecycle of the solr search request](https://home.apache.org/~hossman/rev2017/), but he doesn’t mention anything about how we handle/cleanup the `indexsearcher`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that you don't interact with Lucene's IndexSearcher directly. That's Solr's responsibility, and kept away from you as the user of Solr.

The only place you kind-of interface with the searcher when using Solr, is through [the auto commit setting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html#UpdateHandlersinSolrConfig-autoCommit).

When issuing a commit or an optimize, the current index reader will be closed and a new one will be opened. When issuing those commands, you have the option of telling Solr you want to wait until a new searched as been opened before it returns, allowing you to be sure that your changes have become visible (through `waitSearcher`).

Other than that, the lifecycle of the searcher (which can be summed up as "stay alive until changes to the index have been made, then reopen a new one") is completely hidden away from the outside world.

Comment: You also can tap into Solr's IndexSearcher by means of listeners that populate the caches: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/964cc88cee7d62edf03a923e3217809d630af5d5/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/solrconfig.xml#L542-L570